# TextOutW showing differently on screen vs printer

Tags: winapi, printing, vb6, dpi

We have a VB6 application used for printing that we cannot rewrite in .NET at this time. :) The problem we're looking to solve is that the printed text does not match the UI preview exactly. We have a custom text box control that handles painting and printing by itself using ExtTextOut and TextOut respectively. Their output should be the same but, given the same font, text may be larger on the screen or the printer. The heights are perfect, it is just the spacing and character width that differs. I am not yet convinced this is a font kerning problem but the difference does depend on printer DPI for both spacing and character width. Higher DPI, bigger difference. 4000 DPI results in minutely thinner characters. But I could be convinced we're handling DPI wrong somewhere.

The following code is from the printing side of things that sets up the font and prints some text.

```
fntHeight = MulDiv(m_Font.SIZE, GetDeviceCaps(printerDC, LOGPIXELSY), 72)

fnt = CreateFont(-fntHeight, 0, escapement, escapement, FW_BOLD, Font.Italic, Font.Underline, _
Font.Strikethrough, Font.Charset, 0, CLIP_LH_ANGLES, FontQuality, 0, Font.Name)

SelectObject(printerDC, fnt)

TextOutW(printerDC, x, y, StrPtr(strOutputText), Len(strOutputText))
```

The paint code for the UI is very much the same. The problem users see: the UI is not a good gauge for knowing when a text field's size is too small because if text on the printer DC is slightly wider than the screen DC, the final character, such as a period, is cut off.

This difference varies with font size and at 28 the difference is 0. It can easily vary between +14 and -14, with either the printed or painted text width being larger. I've been so far unable to find out what causes TextOut, ExtTextOut and GetTextExtentPoint32 to give different results.

This code calculates the difference and is used by the paint event in an attempt to adjust spacing to account for it but it would be better if we could find out why there's a difference in the first place, as it can't account for character width differences. GetTextExtentPoints32 is hidden behind the call to TextWidthU.

```
' Call GetTextExtentPoint32W(hdc, StrPtr(strText), Len(strText), textSize)
printerTextWidth = TextWidthU(printerDC, strOutputText) * (screenXdpi / printerXdpi)
screenTextWidth = TextWidthU(UserControl.hdc, strOutputText)
totalDifference = printerTextWidth - screenTextWidth
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Text rasterizer aligns all characters on pixel boundaries. For example letter 'i' can have 3 pixels width for 96 DPI, but 5, 6 or 7 for 192 DPI. If you want to match on-screen and printer widths, you should calculate widths based on printer resolution and appropriately adjust screen positions.

You can adjust positions of individual letters, whole words, or leave on-screen layout as is, but cut or extend right margin depending on printer text size.

MS Word adjusts letter positions (observe space between letters):

[image]

Interesting starting point:
http://www.antigrain.com/research/font_rasterization/index.html#FONT_RASTERIZATION

Comment: That explains it. That article helps a lot.